# FATAL EXCEPTION RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android

I got a sample apk and when installed on two different Android devices having both Gingerbread v2.3.6, the app's behavior is different. In one device, the apk works perfectly. But in other device, the app is not launching.

The error log is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5021): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hello.sample/com.hello.sample.HelloActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/data/com.hello.sample/lib/libhello.so
```

I have checked the device directory and libhello.so is in /data/data/com.hello.sample/lib folder. Also, I tried to put libhello.so in system/lib. Then also I got the same error when clicking on the app's icon. I have extracted the apk and see only libhello.so in the lib folder. How to solve this issue? Is it possible to do anything in the android/framework to solve this? I don't want to change the source code of apk since it is working on the other device.

Comment: maybe the sample sdk compiled for heigher api? make sure the manifest sets the minimum sdk level for at least 9. (Gingerbread)

Comment: The same app is working in another Anndroid device Ginger bread v2.3.6. So I think there is no issue in app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four types of System Image :

**armeabi
armeabi-v7a
MIPS
x86**

While compiling the .so file using native sdk pls build for all four types

Some devices systme image differ

One more thing ..
In lower version mobile :

Library folder is named as lib

in latest version

Library folder is named as libs

Check out This editted answer

Comment: @indira while loading the libhello.so loads with path that created programatically

Comment: /data/data/com.hello.sample